# TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time) missing seconds?

Tags: logging, logparser, iis

When I run log parser using the code below I get the data and time field together as expected but it is missing the seconds.  How do you get it to also list the seconds? The two fields look like,

date                      time
3/13/2013         0:00:02

Once I run it using the code below it looks like this but is missing the seconds,

timestamp
3/13/2013 0:00

```
LogParser "SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time) as timestamp INTO iisLog.csv FROM \\appdev1\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex130313.log" -i:iisW3C -o:csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Those date and time fields do not look to be of type TIMESTAMP, they've been likely parsed as STRING types. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP(STRCAT(date, ' ', time), 'M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss')`.

Comment: Annoyingly, LogParser's `STRCAT` only supports calls with exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: Ooops, you're right. The unreleased 2.3 version does support multiple arguments :-)